# Breqn and amsmath intlimits option clash

Tags: amsmath, breqn

When the intlimits option of the amsmath package is set along with breqn package, the subscripts and superscripts of integral symbols are not placed above and below in displayed equations as they should. Try for instance the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \int_{a}^{b}\!f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `breqn` command changes the meaning of `\int`, so the `intlimits` option has no effect.

The documentation of `breqn` doesn't talk about this; however, saying

```
\renewcommand{\intlimits}{\displaylimits}
```

cures the problem.

---

The `\;` space before the differential seems excessive, usually `\,` is preferred.